# Holding keywords in atoms

Tags: clojure

Is there an easier/more idiomatic way to store/swap keywords in atoms than:

```
(def a (atom :a))
(defn change-a [new-kw] (swap! a (fn [_] new-kw)))
```

No use case as yet, just wondering. It's also entirely possible that I'm missing something, and this kind of thing shouldn't happen/never actually happens in the wild because [some other pattern] is a much better solution.

Comment: How is the fact that it's a keyword relevant? It's hard to answer this question without a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @tolitius why didn't you make your response an answer? I'd pick it if it were.

Comment: If you want to use `swap!` instead of `reset`, you could do `swap! a (constantly :b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

atoms can be either swapped ([CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)) or reset to a different value. Swapping is done with a modifying function e.g. :

```
user=> (swap! (atom 41) inc)
42
```

Notice that a previous (e.g. current) value of an atom is taken into a count when swapping.

[Reseting](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/reset!) a value of an atom is done "*without regard for the current value*":

```
user=> (reset! (atom 41) 42)
42
```

In your case it could be used as:

```
(reset! a :b)
```

In case you'd like to reset a value of an atom keeping the CAS semantics, you can [compare-and-set!](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/compare-and-set!) it:

```
user=> (def a (atom 41))
#'user/a
user=> (compare-and-set! a @a 42)
true
user=> @a
42
```

Comment: Is verifying the success of the operation the only reason to prefer `compare-and-set!`/"CAS semantics"?

Comment: if you mean "prefer" to `reset!`, `compare-and-set!` is a bit lower level, and allows you to be more "pre deterministic". for example an atom can be changed (by another thread, function, process, logic..) after you set it to 41, and if you care to know that, (that it is no longer 41) before setting it to 42, you would use `compare-and-set!`, if you don't care, you can use `reset!`. [compareAndSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet-V-V-) in Java works the same way: same idea.